# Languages in combo box not displayed correctly

Tags: html, character-encoding

I am using the code as follows

```
    <select style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS;">
    <option>Select Language</option>
    <option value="ar">Arabic — العربية</option>
    <option value="bn">Bengali — বাংলা</option>
    <option value="bg">Bulgarian — български</option>
    <option value="ca">Catalan — Català</option>
    <option value="zh_CN">Chinese (Simplified) — 中文（简体）</option>
    <option value="zh_TW">Chinese (Traditional) — 中文 (繁體)</option>
    <option value="hr">Croatian — Hrvatski</option>
    <option value="cs">Czech — čeština</option>
    <option value="da">Danish — Dansk</option>
    <option value="nl">Dutch — Nederlands</option>
    <option value="en" selected="">English</option>
    <option value="en_GB">English (UK) — English (UK)</option>
    <option value="fil">Filipino — Filipino</option>
    <option value="fi">Finnish — suomi</option>
    </select>
```

but when i open it in the browser it is not displayed correctly it is displayed as follows

[image: like this]

how can i solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the encoding in your browser change it to utf-8 ....so it get works

Answer (score 2):

It's simply a character encoding mismatch. The browser is trying to interpret the text in some other encoding than it's really in. Make sure the HTML is output encoded in some suitable encoding like UTF-8 and that you properly tell the browser this encoding. Use an HTTP `Content-Type` header and/or an HTML meta tag to do that.

How exactly you need to do that depends on how exactly you serve/generate the page.

Comment: i tried this <meta charset="utf-8" content="utf-8" />
<meta content-type="utf-8" /> then also not working

Comment: Content-Type text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date Mon, 03 Dec 2012 13:09:41 GMT
Server Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding chunked
Request Headersview source
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control max-age=0
Connection keep-alive
Cookie JSESSIONID=94FD13ADD90DB66D9CBAD440F25D57E1
DNT 1
Host 10.0.0.25:8000
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1

Comment: Well, there you go. Change that `Content-Type` header to UTF-8. I don't know how since you don't say how you serve the page.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this. It works fine on my browser. firefox 10.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I just use this website when I wanna insert some japanese words into my website:

http://mylanguages.org/converter.php

Just convert to unicode and paste it in your line of codings. simple as that.